# Executing an AJAX call within another AJAX call (no jQUERY)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using a third party API to upload a video to that server. Once I have uploaded the video I make a verification call to check if all the file has been uploaded ('verifyUpload()').  If all the file has been uploaded then great, otherwise I resume the upload ('resumeUpload()') from the last byte that was uploaded.  The problem that i am having, and I do not understand why, is that my 'resumeUpload()' does not appear to be executing - have i coded this incorrectly?

In the console I can see the following lines executing from resumeUpload():

console.log('vim.resumeUpload() ...');

console.log('stringArgument: ' + stringArgument);

But instead of the line:
*xmh.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', stringArgument);*

being  executed I am seeing :
xmh.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', 'bytes */*');

being executed from verifyUpload().

verifyUpload()

```
 // VERIFY UPLOAD (SO FAR)
var verifyUpload = function(){
console.log('verifying upload() ...');

var xmh = new XMLHttpRequest;

xmh.onreadystatechange = function(){
    
    console.log('xmh.readyState111: ' + xmh.readyState);
    console.log('xmh.status111: ' + xmh.status);
    
    if(xmh.readyState == xmh.HEADERS_RECEIVED){
        console.log('VERIFY RESPONSE HEADERS: ' + xmh.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log('getResponseHeader(\'Content-Range\')' + xmh.getResponseHeader("Range"));
        
        var range = xmh.getResponseHeader("Range");
        var rangeArray = range.split('-');
        var bytesUploaded = rangeArray[1];
        bytesUploaded = Number(bytesUploaded);
        
        var leftToUpload = vim.vidFileSize-bytesUploaded;
        console.log('bytesUploaded: '+bytesUploaded);
        console.log('byteLeftToUpload: '+ leftToUpload);
        
        // IF ALL THE FILE HAS BEEN UPLOADED TO THE SERVER
        // COMPLETE UPLOAD
        if(leftToUpload == 0){
            completeVidUpload();
        }else{
            // NEED TO RESUME UPLOAD FROM WHERE WE LAST LEFT OFF
            vim.bytesToUploadFrom = bytesUploaded + 1;  
            var stringValue = 'bytes '+vim.bytesToUploadFrom+'-'+vim.vidFileSize+'/'+vim.vidFileSize+'';
            console.log('stringValue: '+ stringValue);
            resumeUpload(stringValue);
        }  
    } 
}
xmh.open('PUT', vim.upload_link_secure);
xmh.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', 'bytes */*');
xmh.send();
}
```

resumeUpload():

```
 // RESUME UPLOAD WHERE LEFT OFF
var resumeUpload = function(stringArgument){
console.log('vim.resumeUpload() ...');
console.log('stringArgument: ' + stringArgument);

var xmh = XMLHttpRequest;

// SET EVENT LISTENERS
// SET EVENT LISTENERS
xmh.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgres, false);
xmh.addEventListener('load', uploadComplete, false);
xmh.addEventListener('error',uploadError, false);

xmh.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmh.readyState == xmh.HEADERS_RECEIVED){
        console.log('VERIFY RESPONSE HEADERS222: ' + xmh.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log('getResponseHeader(\'Content-Range\')222' + xmh.getResponseHeader("Range"));
    }
}
xmh.open('PUT', vim.upload_link_secure);
xmh.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', stringArgument);
xmh.send();
```

}

Comment: _But instead of the line: xmh.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', stringArgument);_ -  I don't see anywhere that you log `xmh.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', stringArgument);`

Comment: I can see from the browser development environment in the 'request header' section what i have sent

Comment: did you add `new` as I mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed `new` in `resumeUpload` here:

```
var xmh = XMLHttpRequest;
```